# Auto complete preselects obscure method before basic language constants (like false)

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm

This may have been asked many times. When entering code, my intent in the pic is to `return false;`, here are the autocomplete suggestions I get:

[image: autocomplete suggestions I get]

Can I force PhpStorm to preselect false before all other obscure (aka much more infrequent targets)? That would improve (much) my user experience.

Sorry for dumb question, I could not find it here.

PhpStorm 2016.1.1, OSX 10.11.4

Comment: For me the `false` (the top most entry) is preselected by default (code completion popup appeared automatically). Quite possibly you have used another method before (e.g. by mistake) so it gives such entries a bit higher score. If you use "false" entry once of twice it should put it higher again. On another hand -- you have "A" as sorting order (Lexicographically; bottom corner of code completion popup) so "false" should have priority anyway (it is the case here .. just it's not selected). Maybe try "File | Invalidate Caches..." ?

Comment: Maybe you did something in the past to the Registry? Please show what you have there for `ide.completion.*` entries --- 1) "Help | Find Action" 2) search for `registry` 3) open it 4) find those entries (you can play with them if you wish -- user modified ones will be in bold font)

Comment: @LazyOne : not registry for sure, was unaware of its existence till you commented !!! Am playing my fave game right now (invalidate/restart).

Comment: @LazyOne : no amount of toying with preferences and restarting could give me the proper selection. Back to coding (albeit inefficiently) : you have no idea how many time i have returned or assigned to bool `fastcgi_finish_request()`, which cant be easily selected for delete. Training myself to type in full a bunch of things.

Comment: No real ideas why it's like that. Only these suggestions: 1) Try with all 3rd party (not bundled by default) plugins disabled -- sometimes they do interfere 2) Maybe try yesterday's [2016.1.2 EAP build](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/05/phpstorm-2016-1-2-eap-145-1503/) -- maybe something fas changed since 2016.1.1 3) How does it work in brand new empty project? 4) try custom live template (e.g. `rf[tab]` will do you `return false;` -- I, for example, have `rt` for `return $this;`)

Comment: 5) I could also suggest to delete ALL indexes / IDE generated files altogether .. just not sure if this will actually help (`~/Library/Caches/<PRODUCT><VERSION>` folder)

Comment: @LazyOne update : 1) no extensions, no change, 2) EAP no change, 3) new project works, so it is `$this->project->index->isMessedUp` 4) rt works (**thanks a lot for that**) 5) no change.  Back to coding now, i will later edit the OP to indicate what i tried ... with lots of help from you. Thanks.

Comment: If it's this project only .... 1) Backup and delete your project settings (while IDE is closed, of course) -- `.idea` subfolder 2) Launch IDE and point to that folder to recreate project from scratch 3) See if it will work; if not -- recover from backup 4) if it does -- try do basic configuration (e.g. additional libraries/folders etc) to see if still works. Most of the individual (shareable) files can be recovered from backup copy (dictionary, deployment, scopes etc etc).

Comment: @LazyOne belated updated : i have followed all the steps you suggested last, still no avail. The issue appears as soon as indexing is complete on the new project 'from scratch' ... i will just toss it on PhpStorm forums and eventually youtrack.  Thanks for your help. This is very `unproductive`.

Comment: There's a bug with type inference. As you can see in your screenshot `false` constant doesn't have type for some reason. We'll investigate and fix it. Thank you for the report!

Comment: @artspb maybe maybe not. I get the same behaviour if I try `return n` (null ,  it is so far in the list that i have to type it in full). Should I update bug report (youtrack) with more examples ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg `null` also has no type.

Comment: @artspb ... ah , my bad. I totally misunderstood your initial remark. There are however other really strange completion lists in that project that do not involve php intrinsics. Where to show them efficiently ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg It's better to file a new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , after some time, I have opened a bug report in Jetbrains's Youtrack (WI-32340).

follow the conversation **[here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32340)**